# How to build project dependencies from source jar-s with maven

Tags: maven-3

I have a project, which is building with maven 3. While building project maven downloads a lot of dependencies (jars). I want to build all this dependencies from source-jars, which I get from maven repository with maven dependency plugin.

But this source jars doesn't contain any pom or other things for building. How I can build them with maven??

Comment: First question: What is the intention of rebuilding everything which is already in the repository ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You need to get the source from the project's source repository. The source-jars are just for helping developers debug dependencies.